# How to count number of neighbors in a matrix?

Tags: c++, dynamic, file-io, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

Okay so I am making the game of life in C and I can't figure out how to count the neighbors from the matrix..

Here is my current code

http://pastebin.com/8fTdbpfs

Sorry I think it just looks better on pastebin.

Comment: I would suggest posting the portion of the code that's relevant. You'll get more answers if people don't have to search a few thousand lines of code for your neighbor calculation.

Comment: Well it's all relevant because I was hoping if there was anything I needed to change they could let me know. Also the code is very small anyway @jcyost

Comment: I cannot open that link, maybe it is blocked by GFW.

Comment: @leeduhem lol its pastebin, how is it blocked? try this http://pastebin.com/SiWk6xFJ

Comment: @MattRay This one still does not work for me. Sigh.

Comment: @leeduhem Here try this http://hastebin.com/yabuxaxabi.vala

Comment: I am afraid this site would not be available for me in a few years.

Comment: Hopefully dropbox! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2216597/Untitled.cpp
@leeduhem

Comment: This one I can see :-)

Answer (score 0):

For cell at location `(i,j)`, i.e. i row, j column, coordinates of all its eight neighbors are

```
(i-1,j-1) | (i-1,j) | (i-1,j+1)
----------+---------+----------
(i,  j-1) | (i  ,j) | (i  ,j+1)
----------+---------+----------
(i+1,j-1) | (i+1,j) | (i+1,j+1)
```

In a two-dimensional array `array[row][col]`, you could access them by `array[i][j]`. Of course, you need to make sure every coordinates are valid before you try to access cell at that coordinate, you can using the following condition to make this check:

```
// for coordinate (i, j) in array[row][col]
if ((0 <= i) && (i < row) && (0 <= j) && (j < col)) {
    /* access array[i][j] */
}
```

Comment: I just can't figure out how to count the neighbors and check for the bounds! :(

Comment: I mean I know how to write the basic if statements that check if the cell is alive then ++count but I don't know how to check for bounds

Comment: So then inside that if do I do if(array1[i][j] == alive) count++ ??

Comment: Sorry I'm new to c++ and I'm honestly wanting the answer handed to me but I'm just pretty confused on this

Comment: @MattRay If that is what you want, then a direct google on "game of life c++" could give you plenty of codes. Read them, try to understand, then you may write a better one on your own.

Comment: Honestly I have been trying that and they suck, please answer this for me.. is this what you mean? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2216597/Untitled%20copy.cpp

Comment: @MattRay This is counting all the alive cells, not just the neighbors of some cell.

Comment: So it's counting all the alive cells around a specific cell right?

Comment: @MattRay No, it is counting all the alive cells in your whole matrix. To count all the alive neighbors of `(i,j)`, only check these eight coordinates that I given you in my answer.

Comment: Agh this is annoying. I thought that's what I did in here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2216597/Untitled%20copy.cpp